# Lotto simulator in Python

Tags: python, performance, simulation, cython

I wrote a rather inapt lotto simulator in Python, showing how long it would take to win the jackpot. I ran a similar application implemented in C and it is so much faster. I know you can't compare the two, but I wonder anyway if there is room for performance improvement in my code. By the way, I converted my code using Cython into C, with no speed gain.

```
import random, locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
r_list = []
super_number = 0
my_super_number = 5
my_list = [[3, 4, 45, 7, 23, 33], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [13, 43, 33, 15, 17, 18], [11, 14, 2, 17, 33, 13],
           [1, 2, 14, 15, 25, 26], [23, 26, 37, 40, 43, 44]]  # each list within corresponds to 1 games per drawing
match_list = []
iteration = 0
number_matches = 0


def fill_random_list():
    for i in range(6):
        # print (random.randint(1,49))
        r_list.append(random.randint(1, 49))


def return_matches(lista, listb):
    # print set(lista).intersection(listb)
    return set(lista).intersection(listb)


def return_number_matches(l_matches):
    if l_matches:
        return len(l_matches)


def print_communicate(v_iteration, v_number_matches, v_guess, v_r_list, v_match_list, v_super_number,
                      v_my_super_number):
    print (
    'Drawing No.: ' + locale.format("%d", v_iteration, grouping=True))
    print ('My guess: ' + str(sorted(v_guess)) + ', Super Number: ' + str(v_my_super_number))
    print ('Result :' + str(sorted(v_r_list)) + ', Super Number: ' + str(v_super_number))
    print ('My hits: ' + str(sorted(v_match_list)) + ', Amount of hits: ' + str(v_number_matches))
    print ('Time to win: ' + str(calculate_time_to_win(v_iteration)) + ' Years')
    print ('---------')


def calculate_time_to_win(v_drawings):
    return (v_drawings/2)/365  # calculate years assuming participation in 2 lotteries a week


def draw_lottery(v_hits, v_with_super_number):  #v_hits: number of hits until termination, v_with_super_number: include super number 'yes' or 'no'
    global iteration, number_matches, r_list, match_list, my_list, super_number, my_super_number
    jackpot = False
    while not jackpot:
        fill_random_list()  # draw lottery results
        super_number = random.randint(1, 9)  # draw super number
        for guess in my_list:
            match_list = return_matches(r_list, guess)
            number_matches = return_number_matches(match_list)
            if number_matches == v_hits:
                if v_with_super_number == 'yes':
                    if my_super_number == super_number:
                        print_communicate(iteration, number_matches, guess, r_list, match_list, super_number,
                                          my_super_number)
                        jackpot = True
                if v_with_super_number == 'no':
                    if my_super_number != super_number:
                        print_communicate(iteration, number_matches, guess, r_list, match_list, super_number,
                                          my_super_number)
                        jackpot = True
            match_list = []
            number_matches = 0

        if jackpot:
            break
        else:
            iteration += 1
            print 'Drawing No.: {0}'.format(iteration) + ' Years: {0}\r'.format(calculate_time_to_win(iteration)),
            r_list = []
            match_list = []
            number_matches = 0


def iterate(number): 
    for i in enumerate(range(number), 1):
        print('Round: ' + str(i[0]))
        draw_lottery(6, 'no')  


def main():
    iterate(1)
    print 'END!'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `randint` can generate many numbers at once.  No need to call it many times.

Comment: In fact `fill_random_list` is already implemented in `random` module, it's called `random.sample()`.